# Rails performance when joining databases on different servers

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

To give us more scalability we are planning to break our one huge MySQL database (with about 50 tables) into several databases on different servers. We are working in Rails 3.

Clearly we want to avoid needing to do joins from tables that live on different servers but this will be unavoidable at times.

To help us figure out the eighth way to partition our database (into 3 new databases/servers or into 12?) we want to understand what performance issues (or not) we will encounter when we access information that requires joining between them.

What is your experience with this? Any rules of thumb? Any gems or tools? Any warnings and caveats? What about caching? What about backups, reliability?

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of any automatic way to join tables across separate physical database servers within Rails. I imagine you would need to perform a manual join within your code, which will be substantially slower than an in-database join.

One option you may want to consider is using the FEDERATED engine within MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html